# Clustering on Geoserver layer appearing out of the map

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, sld, clustering

We are using Geoserver and openlayers to display maps. Geosever layer provides list of sites, since there were many we did a clsutering using Styles.

But the problem is when we zoom out completely some of the clustered points are appearing out of the map.

Please help me to know the actual issue with this. i want the clustered point to be within the bounds of the map.

go to aekos.org.au and select user defined locations. Add some layers to see what I am talking about.

Comment: It seems that the system are using some cache information stored in cache for the large scale levels. Are you using geowebcache technique?

Comment: Yes we are using geowebcache- i even disabled it - but still the same issue.